# Non case sensitive search case sensitive replace

Tags: sed, find-and-replace

How do I search/and replace like this using sed or another tool

```
 FOO => BAR
 Foo => Bar
 foo => bar
```

That is: Look for foo regardless of case, and replace with the same case pattern.

One "solution" is to run sed once for each case-sensitive pattern but it becomes more work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include information like the program and/or OS you're talking about.  also include what you've tried already and what the results were.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hope my edit is enough. I accept solutions for Linux or Windows

Comment: This is straight forward `sed -i -r -e 's/FOO/BAR/g' -e 's/Foo/Bar/g' -e 's/foo/bar/g' file`

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206197/case-sensitive-replace-of-known-words-with-sed)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

S="NewYorkCity"         # search string
R="minneapolis"         # replace template (in lowercase)
declare -u T            # -u: automatic convert content to upper case
for ((I=0; I<${#S}; I++)); do    # loop over each single letter of $S
  if [[ "${S:$I:1}" =~ [A-Z] ]]; then   # upper case?
    T="${R:$I:1}"       # copy single letter to $T (convert to upper case)
    echo -n "$T"        # print single upper case letter without linefeed
  else
    echo -n "${R:$I:1}" # print single letter unaltered without linefeed
  fi
done
```

Output:

MinNeapOlis

---

Same code, more compact:

```
A="NewYorkCity"        # search
B="minneapolis"        # replace (must be in lowercase)
declare -u X
for ((I=0; I<${#A}; I++)); do if [[ "${A:$I:1}" =~ [A-Z] ]]; then X="${B:$I:1}"; echo -n "$X"; else echo -n "${B:$I:1}"; fi; done
```

Comment: Ok so sed or other tools cannot do that...